# How can I install perldoc on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, perl, software-installation

Ubuntu 10.10 comes with Perl 5.10.1 pre-installed, but strangely enough `perldoc` isn't part of the package.

```
$ perldoc
You need to install the perl-doc package to use this program.
```

How can I make this feature available?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid saying it, but did you try installing [perl-doc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/perl-doc)?

```
# apt-get install perl-doc
```

Comment: You will need to execute that command as root.  In Ubuntu this is usually done using `sudo` before the command.

Comment: @Steven I never include `sudo`, it's not technically part of the command, but yes, like all package installs it needs to be run as root

Comment: Users normally use the software center or a package manager gui for installing packages

Comment: @txw Well, this explains why I normally don't answer Ubuntu questions :). If you're already on the command-line and have the package name right in front of you I would expect most people to use `apt-get` or `aptitude`, but maybe that's not the case

Comment: @Michael : The command was what I was after. I already knew that I needed to install `perl-doc`... just wasn't sure what command to use.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Well... you can always also use the commandline in Ubuntu, but most users just do not want to go anywhere near it :D

Comment: for n00bs like me, its not obvious whether this needs to be a cpan install or an apt-get or download a tar or a .dmg from somewhere.

Comment: I came here after not seeing perl-doc in the list from `apt-cache search perl` I just skimmed it looking for the p's and I didn't realize is the output of that command isn't sorted. So, there's more than one section starting with 'p'... Maybe it's broken down by repo.

Comment: Go'dammit! Why oh why is the thing called `perldoc` everywhere, but it needs to be installed using `perl-doc`??! I had to google it because the totally obvious `sudo apt-get install perldoc` didn't work out. If this  first experience with Perl is any indication then I'll soon be done with it again.

Comment: Yeah, ubuntu packages dont list this library at all using apt-search even like perl-doc nor perldoc, though there list myriads of packages named in the form libname-perl, so I expected libperldoc-perl, maybe that could be the reason, why it could not be considered stupid saying that the way you did in the answer.

Comment: Usually it will say "install with apt install perl-doc" so this is way more confusing than it should be. But the answer is correct, thank you! (Although personally I just `sudo apt install perl-doc`)

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `perl-doc` package. It tells you right there in the error message.

Comment: You can use the software center to install any software package

Comment: using perl gets normal people into learned helplessness with all that cpan, cpanM, Mcpan and modules that have different names than printed in the error. After a while I started to try one thing and then throw my hands up and google.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply install the perl-doc package?

Use your favorite package manager, for example synaptic or
`sudo aptitude install perl-doc`